# missing data without baseline characteristics measurements in one survey data

Tags: regression, missing-data, survey, research-design

Suppose I obtained two survey data $D_1,D_2$. (I did not design surveys and I am told to conduct analysis. The survey sample is not a probability sample but a "census" of convenient sampling.) In $D_1$, the survey collected population characteristics. I found some outcomes of interest is related to population characteristics. $D_2$ is collected at later time. Somehow some population who participated $D_1$ survey also participated $D_2$ survey. The goal is compare some outcomes in $D_2$ against those in $D_1$.

Firstly, the data is unbalanced in the sense that some people were measure twice and some were not. Secondly, in $D_2$, the designer forgot to collect characteristics. Thirdly, some outcomes of $D_2$ has >50% non-response rate. Lastly, some responses were multi-choice with multi-response. From what I saw on the survey question, it seems that the survey asked too many questions and prohibited a lot of people answering the question.(Mostly, they have lost patience for filling out the forms. If this is the case, I do not know whether I can guess this is MAR or not.) This leads to a natural missing data pattern as that in longitudinal setting for both $D_1$ and $D_2$. $D_1$ has very mild missing data pattern.(There is <5% missing data for each relevant variable.)

$Q:$ From $D_1$, I concluded possible association between characteristics and some related outcomes of $D_1$ to be compared with those in $D_2$. Without the knowledge of $D_2$'s characteristics, it seems that I am in no position to conduct multiple imputation. To complicates the story further, the data has repeated measurements for some subjects.(Even those subjects who had 2 measurements may have missing responses in $D_2$.) Is there a way to hopefully multiple impute the data? Currently, the missing data profile differs from those not missing for some characteristics. Thus I am leaning towards MNAR. My first thought is that I need some proxy for the missing data in $D_2$. However, I can only use $D_2$'s proxy variable to impute missing data and I do not have that proxy information.

$Q':$ I do not even believe what I am comparing will reflect populational level comparisons, as the survey sample is not a probability sample. How trustworthy are my analysis results?

Comment: Can you give some indication of the sizes of D1 and D2 and the "overlap?"

Comment: @RomkeBontekoe Say $D_1$ has size ~1000 and $D_2$ has size about ~300. The overlap is about ~50 ish. Even with that 50, I am not confidence with the reliability of imputation, as I am predicting $D_2$(different data) from $D_1$. Suppose one of the outcome variable in $D_2$ has 70% missing. 50/300 is about 20% data. That does not account for the other 50% missing.